# object 'rlang_tilde_eval' not found after library updates

Tags: r, r-package, r-library

I have been using the combcoint library for quite some time. Today I installed some new packages in R for my work and since then I have been getting an error, when I try to run the function **bayerhanck**. The error itself:

*Error in p_value_Fisher_bc ~ poly(stat_Fisher_all_bc, 12) * k_dummy :
object 'rlang_tilde_eval' not found*

I assume this there is a technical solution to this, but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: What package is that from? Try reinstalling the package. It's hard to offer any more specific advice without any sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or further details.

Comment: There is a package called rlang in R, although I have never ever heard of it before and I assume this object is from there. I have found this github post, however this is too technical for me https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr/issues/123

Comment: Most likely when you installed those unnamed "new" pacakges, they updated the version of `rlang` that your R was using. But the unnamed package that you are trying to use doesn't know about the newer version. There may be a new version of that package available with changes for the new version of `rlang`. So try reinstalling the package you actually want to use.